# Bounds of the probability of weakly typical set

Tags: information-theory

Theorem 3.1.2 of the book Elements of Information theory states:
\begin{align}
Pr\{A_\epsilon^{(n)}\} > 1 - \epsilon
\end{align}
The bound becomes weaker as $\epsilon$ increases. From the definition of $A_\epsilon^{(n)}$ it seems that more and more sequences are included as $\epsilon$ increases so the probability should increase. So the two results seem to contradict each other. Obviously, the theorem will still hold but it seems to me that this is a side effect of simplifying the notation by choosing $\delta = \epsilon$ in the proof below. Am I correct in saying that in reality the probability increases as $\epsilon$ increases, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the inequality is only valid "for $n$ sufficiently large".
Granted this, you are right.

> Am I correct in saying that in reality the probability increases as $\epsilon$ increases, or am I misunderstanding something?

For a fixed $n$, yes, of course, $Pr\{A_\epsilon^{(n)}\} $ increases as $\epsilon$ increases.

From this point of view it's perhaps perplexing that the bound goes in the other direction, but this (a consequence of choosing $\delta=\epsilon$ - an arbitrary but valid choosing, which "will conveniently simplify notation later") doesn't matter. In that context, we are only interested in what happens for large $n$ and small $\epsilon$.